# How appropriate is it to use « sinon » as a subject-changing device?

Tags: expressions

> {I just said}: **Et sinon**, comment ça se passe la vie ici, dans la cité ?
>
> {With this meaning in mind): Comment ça se passe, **d'ailleurs**, la vie ici, dans la cité ?

I often find myself using « sinon » with the intended meaning of « d'ailleurs », "incidentally", or "on another note" to introduce an incidental statement and digress somewhat – but not so far away as what you may associate with "by the way" that leads you to expect a sudden shift to an unrelated topic.

This particular use of « sinon », however, is not listed as a dictionary entry – which makes me wonder if it might not be so commonly used and perhaps confined to certain regions or a particular age group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour commencer je dirais que ne n'emploierais jamais *d'ailleurs* dans le sens où tu l'emploies dans ton exemple. Par contre j'emploierais *par ailleurs*.

1. **D'ailleurs et par ailleurs**

**D'ailleurs**
N'indique pas un changement total de sujet mais sert plutôt à ajouter un élément nouveau à ce dont on est en tain de parler. C'est plus un lien logique. C'est synonyme de *de plus*, en *outre*.

> - J 'aime beaucoup Zola, d'ailleurs j'ai lu toute son œuvre.
> - Tu es plus près de ton travail maintenant que tu habites ici. D'ailleurs, comment ça se passe, la vie ici, dans la cité ?

**Par ailleurs**
Permet d'ajouter une information complémentaire qui n'a pas nécessairement de rapport avec le sujet dont on vient de parler.

> - J 'aime beaucoup Zola, par ailleurs j'apprécie beaucoup Victor Hugo.
> - C'est bien que tu aimes ton nouveau travail en banlieue. Par ailleurs, ça se passe comment la vie ici dans la cité ?

Voir aussi : [D’ailleurs / Par ailleurs](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dailleurs-par-ailleurs) sur La Langue Française.

2. **Sinon**

*Sinon* est très souvent employé à la place de *par ailleurs* pour introduire un changement de sujet, une digression,  dans la conversation. Cet emploi ne se trouve effectivement pas (encore ?) dans les dictionnaires mais a été remarqué par les linguistes. Voir par exemple : *Les emplois de sinon et le processus d’interprétation*<sup>1</sup> :

> Un dernier type d’emploi est signalé [...] sous le nom de *sinon de complémentarité*. Ce dernier introduit [...] une hypothèse sur l’épuisement d’un topique de discours exploité jusque-là et propose à l’interlocuteur de rebondir sur un autre (*à part ça*) plus ou moins différent [...] Nous avons appelé, quant à nous, ce type d’emploi *sinon de digression*, dans la mesure où l’emploi d’hypothèse négative exprime lui aussi une complémentarité par rapport à un énoncé précédent [...] Notons qu’à l’oral, le sinon de digression est souvent précédé d’un connecteur du type *et*, *ou*, mais, (*et) puis*, (*et / mais*) *après*, qui renforce son fonctionnement comme connecteur discursif, indiquant un changement de topique.<sup>2</sup>

Cet emploi de *sinon*, pourtant bien réel en France dans la langue parlée, est rejeté par les « puristes » :

Académie française :

> [Sinon au sens de Par ailleurs, d’autre part](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/sinon-au-sens-de-par-ailleurs-dautre-part)
> La conjonction sinon signifie « si ce n’est » : je ne sais rien, sinon qu’il est venu ; tous l’aimaient, sinon comme un frère, au moins comme un ami. Elle peut aussi signifier « sans quoi, faute de quoi » : travaillez avec constance et application, sinon vous n’obtiendrez que de médiocres résultats. On ne doit pas ajouter à ces sens celui de « par ailleurs, d’autre part ». On ne dira donc pas, ce que l’on entend hélas trop souvent, il a un bel appartement à Paris, sinon il a aussi une maison en Vendée ; toute sa famille va bien, et, sinon, sa sœur vient de se marier.

Le Figaro:

> [Cinq fautes à ne plus faire pour parler un français académique](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/actu-des-mots/2017/04/13/37002-20170413ARTFIG00007-cinq-fautes-a-ne-plus-faire-pour-parler-un-francais-academique.php)
> À l'instar des «du coup», «bref», «voilà» qui ponctuent à tout bout de champ (et souvent sans raison) nos phrases, le mot «sinon» employé dans le sens de «par ailleurs» est à bannir.

Donc en bref : ta première phrase est très courante et comprise de tous, quant à la deuxième je ne l'emploierais jamais et je ne suis pas sûre qu'elle rende bien ce que tu veux dire.

<sup>1 [Injoo Choi-Jonin et Françoise Migno dans *Langages*, n° 184, décembre 2011](https://www.cairn.info/revue-travaux-de-linguistique-2011-2-page-59.htm)</sup>
<sup>2 Citation complété après discussion avec @StéphaneGimenez.</sup>

Comment: Merci, Laure. The way I initially phrased my question might have come across as a little ambiguous, so I just edited accordingly. I used "d'ailleurs" in this sentence to introduce an incidental statement **somewhat related** to what comes before, as you mention in comparison with "par ailleurs" .

Comment: I was always under the impression that "sinon" is closer to "d'ailleurs" than to "par ailleurs". So it is actually the other way around, huh? ;) Merci.

Comment: @Alone-zee Your use of "changing subject device" is not clear.  And your examples lack context as to what came before in the conversation, there's still nothing showing what you mean by "somewhat related", related to what?  How much related? That's why I used different examples or added to yours.

Comment: Well… to me, “Et sinon" (casual language) sounds a little closer to “d'ailleurs” even though it can be used for both. I'd say it's a good match for “incidentally”/“on another note”, except for the language register. It's usually restricted to small changes of focus within the same topic. And, on a side note (*par ailleurs*), it can also be used with a jokish tone as a complete diversion / topic breaker. Tout ça est bien compliqué. Et sinon, ça va la vie ?

Answer (score 0):

"Et sinon"/"sinon" is really common in the teenager/young adult demographic. It's a simple way to close a subject/discussion and open a new one right after.

"D'ailleurs" is more used when you want to share something related to the current subject and, like "sinon", is use as an opener. "blablabla, **d'ailleurs** blablabla"

To put this two in your example, it would be something like this :

-(something unrelated to the city) "*Tout va bien de mon coté. **Et sinon**, comment ça se passe la vie ici, dans la cité ?*"

-(something made you think about the city) "Oui, mon village est très calme. **D'ailleurs** (or mais/et d'ailleurs), comment ça se passe, la vie ici, dans la cité ?

Comment: This use of *sinon* is not a generation thing, it is also very common among the elderly. It's cross-generational.

Comment: Really ? I've never heard an elderly use it that way. I'll keep that in mind thx.